# Create and launch Espresso test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-studio-3.0

Is there a way to create an espresso test file from a class like does <kbd>Command / Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>?
Same for launch the current test with espresso into the device?

It's very annoying to create/launch every test manually through the whole process of going to the file's hierarchy and then create the launch configuration of it. Neither an option is hidden in options?

If I remember well, these functionalities were available on Android Studio 2.3, I noticed the lack of them from AS3.0. Where did they go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As today, Android Studio 3.1.1 comes with the functionality just as before